# Change swagger url after deploy in .NET 8

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, nswag, .net-8.0

i runned swagger on localhost and everything was great, but after i deployed it cannot adapt the change in url and redirecting everything to the host, here is my code:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
{
settings.DocumentPath = "/api/specification.json";

if(!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    settings.SwaggerRoutes.Add(new SwaggerUi3Route(pathBase, 
        $"/some-service/api/specification.json"));
});

 services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

 services.AddOpenApiDocument((configure, sp) =>
 {
     configure.Title = "SMSService API";
     // Add the fluent validations schema processor
     var fluentValidationSchemaProcessor =
         sp.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FluentValidationSchemaProcessor>();

     configure.SchemaProcessors.Add(fluentValidationSchemaProcessor);
     configure.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT"));

 });
```

After some research i added this

```
 app.UseOpenApi(options =>
 {
    options.PostProcess = (document, request) =>
    {
        var serverUrl = $"http://{request.Host.Value}/some-service";
        document.Servers.Clear();
        document.Servers.Add(new OpenApiServer { Url = serverUrl });
 };
   });
```

After i deployed it's ignoring the `some-service` part in url, how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the goal for `settings.SwaggerRoutes.Add(new SwaggerUi3Route(...))`? Have you tried removing it (looks a bit sus)?

Comment: yep, i tried to remove but i didn't worked

Comment: I actually try to add new openapi server as it was in UseSwagger

Comment: What do you mean by `cannot adapt the change in url and redirecting everything to the host`?

Comment: Do you mean using the public domain instead of `localhost` in the list of servers? You probably need to configure `ForwardedHeadersMiddleware` to make your service aware it runs behind the reverse proxy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Yes, but i cannot use those headers, because they run on nginx-linux and its needs extra configuration, and its something i cannot do.